# SQL - can I do repeated inner joins again on the same column?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have two simple tables, one called `itineraries` that holds details of holiday itineraries and one called `users`, that holds details of users. Other users create itineraries, and users can copy their itineraries and add travel agents, so the copied_from_id is the ID of the original creating user from `users.id`.

I've joined `itineraries.user_id` to `users.id` using the below query which **works perfectly**:

```
SELECT 
itineraries.travel_agent_id, 
itineraries.copied_from_id,
itineraries.user_id,
users.full_name,
users.username

FROM `gadabouting_gadabouting_production`.`itineraries`

INNER JOIN `gadabouting_gadabouting_production`.`users` ON itineraries.user_id=users.id

WHERE itineraries.travel_agent_id='253'
```

Giving me the following output:

```
+-----------------+------------------+---------+-------------+-------------+
| travel_agent_id | original_creator | user_id | full_name   | username    |
| 253             | 501              | 1465    | John Smithy | j.smithy    |
| 253             | 501              | 1465    | John Smithy | j.smithy    |
| 253             | 501              | 1474    | Ben Stockes | ben.stockes |
+-----------------+------------------+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

(The `travel_agent_id` and `original_creator` columns are the same as `users.id`).

What I want to do now is map the `itineraries.travel_agent_id` and `itineraries.original creator` to the `users.full_name` and `users.username` columns (so have the `full_name` and `username` columns printed next to each of the `travel_agent_id` and `original_creator` columns, but I just can't work out how to do it. I've spent hours on it now and can't get my head round it. Do I need to do more joins?

I've looked at several other SO questions about multiple joins but as far as I can see, none of them cover the process of 'going back' **again and again** on the same column as I want to do here.

Is this possible? Would greatly appreciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: There needs to be *a separate join per entity/relation* being introduced. Some systems like SQL Server have CTEs, but those are for *recursive* queries, not just queries wishing to join multiple relations.

Answer (score 0):

You can join in the same table over and over, but you need to use an alias for each one so that you can specify which one you want to use. If you access the result by name, you also need alases for some of the field names.

(It's conventient to use aliases on other tables also, to make the query less verbose.)

```
select
  i.travel_agent_id, 
  i.copied_from_id,
  i.user_id,
  u.full_name,
  u.username,
  ut.full_name as travel_agent_full_name,
  ut.username as travel_agent_username,
  uc.full_name as creator_full_name,
  uc.username as creator_username
from
  gadabouting_gadabouting_production.itineraries as i
  inner join gadabouting_gadabouting_production.users as u on u.id = i.user_id
  inner join gadabouting_gadabouting_production.users as ut on u.id = i.travel_agent_id
  inner join gadabouting_gadabouting_production.users as uc on u.id = i.original_creator
where
  i.travel_agent_id = '253'
```